# Arduino Library not Importing properly Ubuntu 13:10

Tags: ubuntu, arduino, libraries

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64bit. Arduino 1:1.0.5

I'm trying to use the ArduinoFHT library from music labs. The problem is that I can see the library in the 'Sketch->Import Library' dropdown menu, as well as access the examples but whenever I run an example file, say 'fht_adc' I get the error:

'fht_adc.pde:14:40: fatal error: FHT.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.'

If I make my own file and use the dropdown menu 'Sketch->Import Library->ArdunioFHT' I only get a blank line added to the code.

I have tried importing the library into my 'sketchbook/libraries' folder as well as '/usr/share/arduino/libraries' folder and have the same problem.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. 
Re-downloaded the libraries and this time manually extracted them to my 'usr/share/arduino/libraries' file. Works fine this time. 
Don't know what went wrong the first time..